# PowerApps Patch with Defaults function shows grey when selected

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I'm creating PowerApps canvas app. I'm making it using Microsoft developer program account.
My datasource is SharePoint sheets, sheet name is team_data.
Sharepoint sheets has columns ID and new_team.
I have created screen, that contains Text input box and submit button.

To submit the text writen in input box i'm trying to use this code.

```
Patch(
    team_data,
    Defaults(team_data),
    {new_team: Text_input.Text}
);
Navigate(Menu);
```

Error code i get is:

```
Issue

Unexpected vharacters. Characters are used in the formula in an unexpected way.

For example, the character "\' isn't expected after a number, like this: '32\'. A space ('32') would be
expected so that it's just the number 32, or another number (as in '323') would be expected.

Location Button3.OnSelect
```

I found a solution to this.
The solution was to change your browsers native language to English and reload the page, after that it started to work.

I will paste the question still, because some one else might find this usefull.

Answer (score 0):

What was the original language of your browser?

In Power Apps (in fact, Power Fx), **separator is not the same depending the language**. For exemple, if the comma is the decimal separator (like many latin languages), the separator must be a `semi-colon` and the semi-colon must be replaced by `two semi-colons`!

Yes, **as a good practice**, using a browser in English when making a Power Apps it's easier when copy/paste code from the documentation or Stack Overflow.

#### Formula in English:

```
Patch(
    team_data,
    Defaults(team_data),
    {new_team: Text_input.Text}
);
Navigate(Menu);
```

#### Formula in other language where comma is a decimal separator:

```
Patch(
    team_data;
    Defaults(team_data);
    {new_team: Text_input.Text}
);;
Navigate(Menu);;
```

Source : [Formula separators and chaining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/global#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator)